# Can Active MQ listen to port directly without any sender(java application)

Tags: java, queue, activemq-classic, snmp, snmp4j

I want to send data to a port let's say UDP port and from that port I want Active MQ to listen to it directly without any Java application(sender) and then once Active MQ, queue that data then I use my Reciever(Java application) to extract data from queue and use it in my application.

Can I do that, I am working on SNMP traps application and another application is sending SNMP traps data to a udp port 162, now I want a queue to just listen to port 162 and save that data into it's queue, so when my application is available it will extract that data from queue.

or is there any other way I can achieve this.

Comment: The short answer to your question is no; ActiveMQ itself cannot listen directly on a UDP port. You would have to write your own application to act as a proxy or perhaps use an integration framework like Camel (which has an [SNMP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/snmp-component.html) for use-cases like this). In any event, asking for "any other way" to achieve your goal is too vague and will lead to discussion and opinion-based answers rather than fact based answers. Such questions are off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would need to add two components to tie it together and it is a valid use case to want more reliable SNMP data collection by using a messaging queue between the collector and store.

1. Setup ActiveMQ
2. Add a UDP SNMP-to-ActiveMQ proxy listener (StA)
3. Add a ActiveMQ-to-SNMP sender (AtS)

Approaches:

A. Quick and dirty (pure data proxy and store)

You may be able to get away with a Apache Netty listener that grabs the data off the wire and stores it as a BytesMessage (StA), then have the (AtS) listener consume the messages and send to the UDP endpoint of the SNMP server.

Camel may get you there..

StA:
from(netty:udp://.).to("jms:queue:TRAPS.INPUT")

AtS:
from("jms:queue:TRAPS.INPUT").to(netty:udp://snmpserver:port)

ref: https://camel.apache.org/
ref: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/netty-component.html

B. SNMP-aware

Create a SNMP trap listener that handles any SNMP protocol-specific stuff that is needed.

ref: https://agentpp.com/api/java/snmp4j.html